# Merge cells with same year in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to merge the cells one above the months.
Cells Should be merged from 01 to 12 showing year in cell.

Look for the picture for more clarification.
[image]
I have below code, but which show months after run in cell row1.
My idea is to convert above cells to years through vba and apply merge same year at the end.
which is shown in desired output.

Note.
ROW 4 and 5 are just my thinking, which will help year to merge.

```
  Dim a(), i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, x As Range
  With Range("b1:qaz1")
    .MergeCells = False
    .ClearContents
    a() = .Offset(1).Value
    m = Month(a(1, 1))
    j = UBound(a, 2)
    Set x = .Cells(1)
    For i = 2 To j
      If m <> Month(a(1, i)) Or i = j Then
        With Range(x, .Cells(i - IIf(i = j, 0, 1)))
          .MergeCells = True
          .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        x.Value = Format(DateSerial(2000, m, 1), "MMMM")
        m = Month(a(1, i))
        Set x = .Cells(i)
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

After running new program output look like
[image]

Comment: Excel people all know that merging causes trouble. Consider re-phrasing your question to how to achieve the result you want without merging cells, and more people here will be interested in your topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have true dates in your caption row the month and year can be extracted from there. However, the code below converts dates that might have been created using formulas to hard dates before processing them.

```
Sub MergeCaptionsByYear()
    ' 031

    Const CapsRow   As Long = 1                 ' change to suit
    Const StartClm  As Long = 2                 ' change to suit

    Dim Rng         As Range                    ' working range
    Dim Tmp         As Variant                  ' current cell's value
    Dim Cl          As Long                     ' last used column
    Dim Cstart      As Long                     ' first column in Rng
    Dim C           As Long                     ' working column
    Dim Yr          As Integer                  ' year

    Cl = Cells(CapsRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(Cells(CapsRow, StartClm), Cells(CapsRow, Cl)).Copy
    Cells(CapsRow, StartClm).PasteSpecial xlValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    C = StartClm - 1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do
        Tmp = Cells(CapsRow, C + 1).Value
        If Not IsDate(Tmp) And (C <> Cl) Then
            MsgBox "Cell " & Cells(CapsRow, C + 1).Address(0, 0) & _
                   " doesn't contain a date." & vbCr & _
                   "This macro will be terminated.", _
                   vbInformation, "Invalid cell content"
            Exit Do
        End If

        If (Yr <> Year(CDate(Tmp))) Or (C = Cl) Then
            If Yr Then
                Set Rng = Range(Cells(CapsRow, Cstart), _
                                Cells(CapsRow, C))
                With Rng
                    .Merge
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .NumberFormat = "yyyy"
                End With
                SetBorder Rng, xlEdgeLeft
                SetBorder Rng, xlEdgeRight
            End If
            If C > (Cl - 1) Then Exit Do
            Cstart = C + 1
            Yr = Year(Tmp)
        End If
        C = C + 1
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Sub SetBorder(Rng As Range, _
                      Bord As XlBordersIndex)
    ' 031

    With Rng.Borders(Bord)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium                          ' xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Code is good , bit lengthy. works properly for one time. but my dates are changing everytime but they are always in series. As date changes everytime i run this program and error occurs. Need to remove Msgbox, no need on this sheet, but need to work on error. any idea how can i run this program even after from the first run (merged cells) can be replaced with new year.

Comment: Well, I suggest you remove the MsgBox if you don't need it and work on the error, too. The first step is to find out on which line of code the error occurs and then determine the reason for it.

Comment: Yes, working properly now thanks, made some few minor changes. now its working Good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the months range is "B5:AH5"

[image]

```
Sub test()

Dim monthsRng As Range
Set monthsRng = Range("B5:AH5")
monthsRng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Select

For j = 1 To Int((monthsRng.Cells.Count / 12) + 2)
    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) <> 0 Then
    For i = 1 To 12
        ActiveCell.Value = Year(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
        If Year(ActiveCell.Offset(1, i)) = ActiveCell Then
        Selection.Resize(1, i + 1).Select
        Else
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .MergeCells = True
        End With
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Else
    Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Replacing the inner for loop with below code will work irrespective of whether the dates in the `Range("B5:AH5")` in above procedure are formatted as dates or not.

```
For i = 1 To 12
    ActiveCell.Value = Right(Format(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), "DD.MM.YYYY"), 4)
    If Right(Format(ActiveCell.Offset(1, i), "DD.MM.YYYY"), 4) = Format(ActiveCell, Text) Then
    Selection.Resize(1, i + 1).Select
    Else
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

However, in any case you need to format the output in excel as number (without 1000 separator and decimal places) and not date.

Comment: I tried running this code all is working fine but the year displayed after merge is showing "1905". it should show the same year below. and after few run it show month"07" in some cells. can you help me to solve this. I have used the same code as you have given.@NareshBhople

Comment: Its in the "DD.MM.YYYY" Format . i tried running it several times have same issue.

Comment: I got it. Its just formatting issue.  Because when you format 2018 as "dd.mm.yyyy" it becomes "10/07/1905" .... you need to format the row number 4 as "Number" without decimals and 1000 separator. Then it will show 2018, 2019 etc.. Select Row 4 and press "Control + 1" select "Number" Tab. In Category select "Number" and Make "Decimal Places" 0 .. Remove 1000 separator tick .. Removing all the comments above to make this more readable. You can also delete your comments