# Excel Merge Cells according to another column data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem about merged cells.

I have the following data and want to merged cells according another column's data
Ex:

[image]

What can I do , using VBA or formula ?

Thank you !!

Comment: I would recommend that you show what you've already tried.
In my view, a VBA script is the way to go.

Comment: for clue to begin  .. [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979956/merge-cells-with-same-year-in-a-row) or this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68753358/how-to-merge-duplicate-cell-values-in-rows-my-code-is-ignoring-some-of-the-dupl)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.